# Half-open infinite interval is open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How might I show that the half open intervals (-$\infty$, $k$] and $[k, \infty)$ are open sets in the topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ when $k$ is irrational (for instance, $\sqrt{2}$)?

Comment: They aren't always. Was there some condition on $k$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Whoops. Edited.

Comment: You know that $(-\infty,a)$ and $(a,+\infty)$ are open, I presume?

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed.

Comment: If $x \in (-\infty,k]$ where $x$ is rational and $k$ is irrational, what can you say about the interval between $x$ and $k$?

Comment: @kccu if you mean the interval $[x,k]$, that it is closed?

Comment: And a set is open in the topology induced on $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if it is of the form $U \cap \mathbb{Q}$ for some open $U \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed.

Comment: Can you connect these facts, keeping in mind the not unimportant edit to the question?

Comment: @Evan More importantly, $(x,k)$ is nonempty. Since $x \leq k$ but $x\neq k$ ($x$ is rational while $k$ is irrational), it must be the case that $x < k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer When you say the interval ($-\infty, a)$ is open, should I keep a rational or irrational $a$ in mind?

Comment: @kccu Yes, but how does that help with seeing that the half open interval is an open set?

Comment: For the openness of $(-\infty,a)$, it's irrelevant whether $a$ is rational or irrational. But in view of the question, we need only consider irrational $a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm-- I confess I am still not able to connect the facts. Maybe I am being obtuse.

Comment: @Evan Given rational $x \in (-\infty, k]$, we know there exist rationals $a,b \in (-\infty,k]$ such that $x<b<k$ and $a<x$. Then $x\in(a,b)\subseteq (-\infty, k]$. Clearly $(a,b)$ is open in the topology in question. This shows that every point in $(-\infty,k]$ has a neighborhood contained in $(-\infty, k]$.

Comment: It certainly contributes that I don't know how to give a good hint and not give everything right away.

Comment: @DanielFischer The intersection of $(-\infty, k)$ with $\mathbb{Q}$  will not include $k$

Comment: @Evan in regards to Daniel Fischer's proof method, notice that $(-\infty,k] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ does not contain $k$ either.

Comment: @kccu Does saying that every point in $(-\infty, k]$ has a nbhd in $(-\infty, k]$ tell us $(-\infty, k]$ is open?

Comment: @Evan I should have specified an open neighborhood. In which case yes, because for each rational $x \in S:=(-\infty,k]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ there exists an open set $U_x$ (in the topology in question) such that $x \in U_x \subset S$. Hence $S= \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x$ is open. (But drhab's solution below and Daniel Fischer's argument are much simpler and clearer.)

Answer (score 2):

If $k\notin\mathbb Q$ then $$(-\infty,k]\cap\mathbb Q=(-\infty,k)\cap\mathbb Q$$ and $$[k,\infty)\cap\mathbb Q=(k,\infty)\cap\mathbb Q$$

In both cases the RHS is evidently open in $\mathbb Q$ if it is equipped with the topology induced by the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, since it is the intersection of $\mathbb Q$ with an open set in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider a general rational $r$ inside one of these sets and verify that there is an open interval surrounding it that does not reach the boundary.